# Метаданные Mp3 в  Android

Tags: android, java, mp3

Нужно прочитать метаданные Mp3 файла (арт фото, артист, албом....) всё, что нужно для разработки плеера. Не смог сам разобраться какие библиотеки нужны, как я могу достать эти данные на Андроид.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Синий](http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/), [красный](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/), [голубой](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) - выбирай себе любой))

Либо на [Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_(%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)) внизу есть ссылки на стандарты, изучай и можешь читать и записывать напрямую из файла.

Comment: Первую библиотеку скачал,не получаеться добавить она tar.gz расширения,3 установил норм,просто не будет у вас примера использование этой библиотеки?

Comment: Чтобы установить первую, распаковываешь любым адекватным архиватором (7-zip), там в папке dist есть файл JID3.jar вот его и подключаешь в путь компоновки, а далее вот подробный пример http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/samples.html

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] columns = {
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,

    };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
            null, null, null);
            String[] displayFields = new String[]{Albums.ALBUM};

    int[] displayViews = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, displayFields,
            displayViews));
```

Comment: я не пойму как это мне поможет.

Comment: примени и поймёшь; таким образом ты извлечёшь всю необходимую инфу о твоём аудио файле. Используя MediaStore.Audio.Albums, ты олучаешь всю инфу оба альбоме,MediaStore.Audio.Artists - всю инфу об исполнителе, а вообще по этому вопросу лучше внимательно изучить документацию по MediaStore.Audio

Comment: ricky, человеку нужно прочитать инфу из mp3 файла, а не получить ее от контент-провайдера из хранилища...